# Rails - Temporary ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wanna create a method for return of my all objects for some model. The thing is, further than the persisted objects on db, I wanna join some more objects based on some condition. So it would be something like

```
MyModel.all + [some_array].map{|a| MyModel.new(attribute: a)}
```

The thing is: those new records wouldn't be persisted on the db. They would be created on the fly as new records to join the persisted ones. That way I showed kinda works, I get a array of objects of MyModel, but the problem is, since it's not an ActiveRecord relationship, I can't do a `where` on that set of records.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean a where on that set of records?  At the end of that code you should have an array of MyModel objects, some persisted, some not.  If you need to then get a further subset of those objects, you can probably use any Enumerable method, such as select

```
 myarray = MyModel.all + [some_array].map{|a| MyModel.new(attribute: a)}
 #as opposed to myarray.where(attribute: 'key')
 myarray.select {|obj| obj.attribute == 'key' }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... but I wanted to use where instead of select, 'cause the implementation was already like that. Guess I'll have to change it. Just wanted a second opinion. Thanks!